# Writing console output(space seperated text) to seperate columns of excel sheet using Python

Tags: python, xlwt

I have a console output , which has multiple rows of space separated strings.for ex-

> Hi everyone
>
> Hello to all
>
> Welcome to python

I want to write them into separate rows of excel file with each string into separate column for ex-

```
     A1      A2         A3
B1   Hi      everyone
B2   Hello   to         all
B3   Welcome to         python
```

Do we have any (text to columns) utility in xlwt package of python.?

**UPDATE**
I have an exe which has got these print statements ,outputting all at once.I just execute that exe and get the prints on console.I want to read from the console and write to excel sheet like I have explained above.Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import xlwt
process=subprocess.Popen('Test_Project.exe',stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
wb=xlwt.Workbook()
sheet=wb.add_sheet('python')
for rows in range(10):    #let say 10 rows and columns we have
    for cols in range(10):
        out = process.stdout.readline()
        sheet.write(rows,cols,out)
        print out
wb.save('stdoutput.xls')
```

Comment: How about [tag:openpyxl]?

Comment: How do you get the output? Show your code please, is this user input? Is this read from a file? Is this fed to you 1 line at at time or all at once?

Comment: I have updated my question . I am very new to Python and xlwt as well.Any help is appreciated..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you'll want the process to finish before you start procesing the output

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import xlwt
process=subprocess.Popen('Test_Project.exe',stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err = process.communicate()
wb=xlwt.Workbook()
sheet=wb.add_sheet('python')
row = 0
for line in out.split('\n'): 
    for i,wrd in enumerate(line.split()):    
        sheet.write(row,i,wrd)
    row=row+1 
wb.save('stdoutput.xls')
```

Answer (score 3):

Just write it as .csv.

Assuming you've got `row` which is a space-separated string:

```
outfile.write(','.join(row.split())
```

Comment: We are getting some data on the console by running an executable. I have to save that data in excel sheet as a log.can u plz tell me where to do that . because i am not getting how to save the data in csv at runtime. Thanks @lost